# File has bytes - appears to be empty

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

I'm having the following problem:

Some text files (also some binary files) on my system are listed with the correct file size but when I open them, they appear empty.

```
>ls -la
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user   652 Mar 12 16:17 summary.txt
>cat summary.txt
>
```

If I display them in midnight commander I get a list of dots (`......`) and in `vi` a list of `^@`. I'm not sure when it happened, but I guess since the last reboot.

System:

- Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-37-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 21:37:54 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- ext4

Is there a way to fix it?

Edit: I guess it most be somehow correlated with a system reboot. Can I somehow find out by looking at the log files what happened?

Thanks.

Comment: Could perhaps be a partially transferred/downloaded file?  I know that at least several BitTorrent-clients creates files of the size it need for the file it's downloading, and then fill it with NUL - and if the download fails, NUL will be all the file contain.  Don't think it's much you can do; you may have reserved space for the file, but you obviously haven't actually downloaded/transferred it.

Comment: Did you neglect to mention that your system crashed/lost power shortly after you wrote that file?

Comment: The file is corrupted. If the system crashed before you saved the file or just as the file was being written, this is to be expected. Otherwise do a memory test (reboot and choose “memory test” at the Grub prompt, let it run for at least one full pass).

Comment: @BaardKopperud - thanks for the hint, but the file was there the left time I logged into the system, now it's corrupted. I don't know exactly when the problem occurred.

Comment: @psusi - it's a virtual machine on our institutes server infrastructure. I saw that it was rebooted but I don't know if it crashed - definitely right after it was written.

Comment: @Gilles - thank's for the hint, but I can't access Grub (virtual machine)

Comment: @Stephan If it's a VM then you'd need to test the memory of the host.

Comment: Then there you go; it crashed and rebooted before the data hit the disk, so it was lost.

Comment: Ok I'll ask them to check the memory. Somehow I'm not convinced that a crash was the reason, because I could open/modify the files - then a reboot happened and (I guess) after that the content of the files was lost. Any luck with looking at log files?

Comment: It is possible to write to a file, then read it (this reads from cache in ram), then before the file is written to disk to crash the machine, and loose the data. To prevent this then you need to use a journalling file-system (that is configured correctly).

Answer (score 3):

`^@` is a representation of the null byte. You can get a better picture from `xxd` or `od`.

If the contents of the file has been lost, the fix would be to restore it from the version control system or backups.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just executed xxd and it seems that only null bytes are in the file:

0000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000      ................
0000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

-----  
Do you have any idea why that happened - or could I somehow find it out. It would be great if it was only a "one time" thing.

Comment: These things can happen e.g. if two processes write to the same file.

Comment: or if the file has been scrubbed with dd from /dev/zero